# How to use the expandable ListView with database data

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, android-database

I have been trying to use expandable listview to be populated with data from a database, i can display this data in a simple listview (each row for each item on the listview).

However in my app i want to give the option to the user to create groups/lists of items, i will give an example:

**FRUITS**, i can add fruits individually: **apple, watermelon, kiwi, pear..** and then i want to create the group "Red Fruits" that will have "apple" and "water melon" and "Green fruits" that will have "kiwi" and "pear"

I want to be able to chose wich items i want to add to a specifc list and store that list in the database.

I have been searching and so far this is what i got into:

- I need to create a ArrayList of the fruit object. My doubt: The fruits are already added in the database, how will i add items to this arraylist, by the Ids on the databse ?
- How to store this list in the satabase ?
- How to get this ArrayList displayed into a expandable listview ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi the answers

1. Yes, you need to store your fruits in ArrayList and saving the data. For this, follow the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#UpdateDbRow).
2. Create a custom adapter for your ListView, here is a [guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView). For expandable listview adapter,  read the next answer.
3. This [post](http://techlovejump.com/android-expandable-listview-tutorial/) can be helpful.

Cheers!